# Entity form field with inactive records

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form definition like this (for demonstration purposes):

```
$builder->add('field', 'entity', [
    'class' => EntityA::class,
    'query_builder' => function($repo) {
        return $repo->createQueryBuilder('e')
            ->andWhere('e.active = 1');
    }
]);
```

This ensures that only active records can be selected in the dropdown field when using this form.

This leads to this case: When I edit an entity using the form definition from above, and this entity as an inactive `EntityA` assigned, it won't appear in the dropdown field. When I hit the save button, it will get the first active (if any) `EntityA` assigned. Also the form will suggest to the user that a different `Entity` is assigned than it actually is.

The correct way would be that the form displays all active records and the one inactive one that is currently assigned.

I looked into Form event listeners but this seems overly complicated. Also, extending the form just for editing could be a thing but it seems not "the right way" to me.

How can I solve this issue, preferably without using 3rd party bundles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the object and load different data into dropdown depends of type of action: edit/create:

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) 
{
    $data = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();

    $form ->add('field', 'entity', [
        'class' => EntityA::class,
        'query_builder' => function($repo) use ($data) {
             if ($data->getId()) {
                 // Edit mode: append the pre-selected record to dropdown
                 return $repo->createQueryBuilder('e')
                     ->andWhere('e.active = 1')
                     ->orWhere('e.id = :id')
                     ->setParameter('id', $data->getId());
              } else {
                 // Display only active records
                 return $repo->createQueryBuilder('e')->andWhere('e.active = 1');                          
              }  
          }
     ]);
});
```

Comment: if I put this code into the `buildForm` method, I always get `null` for `$object`. the moment of execution is too early at this point.

Comment: Add the field when FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA Event event is triggered (http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html)

Comment: Thank you. I used a combination of `PRE_SET_DATA` and custom field type to scan over my form and change the `query_builder`.